# How to build several versions of a war with different dependencies

Tags: maven, war

I'm facing a situation where I need to build different war with a different set of dependencies, to be both deployable under Tomcat 7 and WebSphere 8 (WebSphere provides tons of dependencies on its own), and I'm looking for the best way to do it.

- Using profiles: is a bad idea, since I can not tell the maven-release to run twice, once with the tomcat profile and once with the websphere.
- Using different executions of the maven-war plugin: works better, but I have to manually exclude every unneeded jar using the "packagingExcludes" configuration (I can not tell maven to use a specific profile or dependencies for each execution), making that configuration pretty fragile
- Using war overlay: maybe a good idea, but I don't like the fact that maven ignores every dependency declared in the original war (thus we could have several version of the same artifact in the second war if we are not very carefull, the configuration is therefore pretty fragile)
- Using assembly: seems to be a bit better than war overlays, still need a lot of manual configuration
- Using different modules: I can not reuse classes declared in one war in the other, and we have a bug in our WebSphere that prevent us from declaring all our classes in a dependent project (JAX-RS annotation are not found if the class using it is inside a jar in WEB-INF/lib, it works only if it is deployed as a class file inside WEB-INF/classes)

How do you handle such situations in your real world projects? What am I missing?

Comment: Why can't you reuse classes declared in a war not in an other module?

Comment: you mean building an artifact with the classes, webresources, configuration, etc. and unpacking everything in each forms of the war? that should work, but there should be something easier?
And I would like to be able to use the same groupId/artifactId/version, but differenciating the builds with a classifier instead of making a different artifact for each deployment.

Comment: You have not answered my question. I would like to know what the problem is with reusing of "classes declared in a war" ?

Comment: If I put classes on warA/src/main/java, I can not reference them from warB/src/main/java, or at least I need some ugly combination of assemblies, dependencies:unpack, etc. to share those classes between the two modules with no code duplication. I would prefer a better option. A smart one.

Comment: I remember, a strange behavior of our WebSphere makes it impossible to find JAX-RS classes living in a jar. They must be on the war src/main/java (WEB-INF/classes).

Comment: Okay, assembly is finally not that bad, with not as much configuration as I thought and correct transitive dependencies management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembly does the job:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>websphere8</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
             <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</exclude>
             </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:*</exclude>
                <exclude>xml-apis:xml-apis:*</exclude>
                <exclude>xerces:xercesImpl:*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.ow2.jotm:jotm-core:*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```